# iPhone button actions

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, storyboard

The issue I am having is that when I am in my main storyboard for my iPhone app and I control-click and drag my button to the .h file I want to associate it with, nothing happens in the .h file and it is really confusing me. I have other pages in the same storyboard that this method worked just fine with. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Not sure if it matters but the last time I tried the click drag was before I released this app, and now I am working on a update for it.

Anyone else have this issue? I have found one possible solution that worked for someone (clearing the PRAM) but that did not help me.

Comment: Did you copy and paste that button from somewhere else?

Comment: no, i created a new button by dragging it from objects to my view

Comment: Are you dragging from the button to the header file that is set as the class of the View Controller within the storyboard?

Comment: what i did was, create a new view controller in the mainStoryBoard, then a made the .h (extending UIViewController) and .m files and dragged the button in the new view controller to the .h file

Comment: not sure if this also will help, but when i click on a view that works fine, i get the .h file appear next to it. but when i click on the view that doesnt work the UIVeiwController class appears next to it

Comment: ok, it seems like i got it working now. for some reason my view controller didnt set the custom class to the one i needed (even though it did for the others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to verify that the name class of your ViewController in the storyboard is the same of your .h file.

Comment: yeah, it seems like that was my problem. I didn't have the viewController I wanted to use set in my storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Press `Ctrl button + drag` the your button to viewController.h then "`Insert Outlet and Outlet Collection`" will be appeared. After that you remove your finger on mouse you will get Outlet box regarding connection. It has connection, Name, Type properties. I think it will be helpful to you.